# Woocommerce: programmatically adding to cart

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a site which sells a virtual product: basically licences, with a start and end date, and a quantity. This doesn't fit well with woocommerce, so I send the required form data directly to the server via Ajax, and the user then has to manually checkout to pay for it.

I thought the obvious way to handle this was with [wc_create_order](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_create_order.html). However, this seems to create a *completed* order, with a status of 'pending payment'. There doesn't seem to be a way to actually pay for the order - the checkout/cart page says that there's no order.

Is the way to do this `$woocommerce->cart->add_to_cart()`? This is a pain - you have to create and insert a post, add post meta, then call [add_to_cart](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#844-958). I can find lost of code fragments to do this, but no definitive documentation on it. Am I missing something?

Comment: I can think of 2 possibilities. 1. Use a virtual [Subscription](http://www.woothemes.com/products/woocommerce-subscriptions/) product. The license would be expired when the subscription expires.  2. Create a custom product type that modifies the price of the virtual product depending on your form inputs.